# Cannot find module I'm exporting

Tags: javascript, database, module, sequelize.js

I can't access this module I'm exporting.  I have no clue what's wrong.

I'm trying to export a database connection so it's available everywhere.

database.js

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

var server = 'aggregatesqlserver.database.windows.net'
var database = 'AGGREGATEDEVDB'
var username = '****'
var password = '****'
var driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host: server,
  dialect: "mssql"
});

try {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}

module.exports = sequelize;
```

When I try to access if from this script

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { createConnection, Connection} from "typeorm";

const db = require('./config/database');

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
      AppModule,
    );

    app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
    app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
    app.setViewEngine('hbs');

    const [results, metadata] = await db.query("UPDATE [dbo].[storedProc] SET someData = RAND() WHERE columnID = 1");

  await app.listen(3000);
    }

bootstrap();
```

It gives me this error no matter what...

```
Error: Cannot find module './config/database'
Require stack:
- /Users/paytondugas/Desktop/RapidTek/nest/SQL/csp_copy/dist/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paytondugas/Desktop/RapidTek/nest/SQL/csp_copy/src/main.ts:7:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

Here's the file system

[image]

Any clue on the problem...?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes such conflicts happen due to using ES5 module syntax instead of ES6 module syntax.

To avoid such problem try using only one module syntax, either the es5 or the es6

Try using

```
import db from './config/database';
```

instead of

```
const db = require('./config/database');
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior happens because you try to import a Javascript file from Typescript file. You can try:

1.

```
import * as db from './config/database';
```

2. Add this characteristic to allow JS modules import in tsconfig.json or your tsconfig

   {
   "compilerOptions": {
   "allowJs": true
   }
   }